# Meteor choking on large file counts in public folder

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to include a Less version of bootstrap in my project, but by the time I've installed all the dependencies, the file count is > 10000 and meteor grinds to a standstill trying to keep up.

I've tried putting it in a folder that starts with a '.' since apparently meteor ignores those, but no change.

How can I force Meteor to ignore a folder so it doesn't choke on stuff it can safely ignore?

Comment: Is your question on processing large LESS files or about uploading assets that Meteor just stores on the server?

Comment: Just large numbers of files being stored in the public directory.

Comment: I experienced Meteor restart/startup lag when my LESS files grew and when they started doing loops. I ended up doing the styles compile outside of Meteor and pure CSS into the project. Not sure if thats your issue. Also CSS does not go in the public folder.